# Swap collections during iteration

Tags: java, tree, nodes

I have a `List` of `Nodes` which contains nested list of `child nodes`. I am trying to iterate through all of them to find a particular node.Currently I start at the `child nodes` from the `root` level, then go one level deep to `sub child node` and so on using `for-each` loop.
This is my code:

```
List<Node> children = root.getChildren();
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found) {

        for (Node node : children) {

            if (!node.getData().toString().toUpperCase().contains("BRANCH")) {
                if(condition){//some processing}
                } else {
                    //swap children with sub children
                    if (children.get(0) != null) {
                        children = children.get(0).getChildren(); // this operation is not possible during iteration
                    }
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

If `child node` doesn't find any match, then I need to swap the collection with `sub child node` and continue iteration and so on. 
Is there a better way to iterate through a nested `nodelist` of children?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. I would suggest recursion, but it is unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @JornVernee: I was trying to build a java hierarchy tree from an arraylist and later convert to json (gson) to render in the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of swapping the collections, you could add the elements to a queue, and keep iterating till the queue is empty (i.e. you didn't find a match). Or you do find a match and return early.

```
public static void algorithm(Node root) {
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = q.poll();

        if(current .getData().toString().toUpperCase().contains("BRANCH")) {
            continue;
        }

        if(condition){
            //some processing
            return;
        } else {
            q.addAll(current.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```

```
algorithm(root);
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't swap like this mid-iteration.  Remember that your for loop is translated in Java like this:

```
for (Iterator<Node> it = children.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Node node = it.next();
    // The rest of it
}
```

So even if you change what `children` is, your iterator stays as it is.

I would suggest using a `Queue` to help you here.

PS Do you really want to skip all of the non-first children?  That appears to be what you're currently doing.

Comment: @ Joe C: that's what I thought too. Also the tree is huge and it gets real complicated moving down. I guess I need to use a different algorithm as you stated. I am just trying to get the first child and all its sub child logic to get to work before going into the other children. I may have to use a for loop or something to cover all siblings. But it's already a nightmare. lol